# how to count length of an associate array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have associate an array as

```
[[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];
```

i want to count length of an array of this after flattered this array my code is following

```js
function lengthOfMultiArray(array = [ [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9] ], temp = 0) {
  for (var i in array) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      this.lengthOfMultiArray(array[i], temp);
    } else {
      temp++;
    }
  }

  return temp;
}

console.log(lengthOfMultiArray());
```

and i am using recursive function to count it but for start of every loop it update temp as 0 and start again with zero.

Comment: `this.lengthOfMultiArray(array[i], temp);` there is no `this` around here, unless you execute that in the global context in non-strict mode, in which it *happens* to be `window`. Also, you execute this recursively but never capture the value or anything.

Comment: You need to add the result of the recursive call to your final result.

Comment: And are you really using default arguments? Or is that just to illustrate what you are doing here in your question? If the later, you should just show an example function call instead.

Comment: You are trying to pass by ref, but it is a primitive datatype and is passed by val.

Comment: Just so you know why this doesn't work, `this.lengthOfMultiArray(array[i], temp);` -- you're passing temp into the function and expecting the function to **change** temp, but number variables are immutable -- a function cannot change a number variable, it can only return a new number.

Comment: just change: `temp = this.lengthOfMultiArray(array[i], temp);` and will work ;)

Comment: @ljcordero Really using `this` will work?

Comment: @Sylwester you are right, without `this` :> `temp = lengthOfMultiArray(array[i], temp)` thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the result of each recursive call to your total. Also, you don't need the `temp` parameter, just a local variable to calculate the total:

```js
function lengthOfMultiArray(array) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i in array) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])){
            total += lengthOfMultiArray(array[i]);
        } else {
            total++;
        }
    }

    return total;
}

console.log(lengthOfMultiArray([ [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9] ]));
```

Comment: Removed the disclaimer since now you can test it and it works :P

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
const array = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];
array.flat(Infinity).length;
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer is not acceptable for `how to count length of an associate array in JavaScript?`.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple recursive solution looks like this:

```js
const sum = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const lengthOfMultiArray = (arr) => 
  Array .isArray (arr) ? sum (arr .map (lengthOfMultiArray)) : 1

console .log (lengthOfMultiArray ([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, [7, 8], 9]]))
```

This simply says that the length of a non-array is `1` and the length of an array is the sum of the lengths of its elements.

You might choose to inline the function `sum` here if you had no other use for it:

```js
const len = (arr) => 
  Array .isArray (arr)
    ? arr .map (len) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b)
    : 1
```

Or, more to my liking, you might break that down even further, introducing an `add` function:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b
const sum = (ns) => ns. reduce (add, 0)
```